# counting machine with function for 1 variable

Tags: python, function, python-3.10

So, I've been trying to make a counting machine to a variable `n`.
I'm using a function to get it done yet it keeps stating that `n=0` which I've used at the beginning of the code.
This is what I'm using.

```
n=0

def cprocess():
    n=n+1
```

It's I guess, pretty simple, but I am a beginner. How do I improve & fix the code?

Comment: If that's the whole code, then you have defined a function but you have not called the function.  You would need to add `cprocess()` to call it.  However, that's not going to work, because you can't modify a global variable unless you use a `global` statement in the function.  This is not the right way to perform this action.  What larger problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call the function, a function only executes code when called. Also, don't use the syntax `x=x+1`, instead use the `+=` operator.

Since you seem new, I'll go step by step:

```py
n=0 # defining our integer variable

def cprocess(): # defining our function
    global n # leave this out if you want, functions and variables tend to be weird sometimes, so by doing this we make sure variable "n" exists
    n += 1 # incrementing variable "n" by 1

cprocess() # calling our function

print(n) # checking our variable
>>> 1 # output of print statement
```

Comment: `global n` doesn't tell that `n` exists, it tells to lookup `n` in the global scope not local

Answer (score 0):

Add `global n` inside the function.

```
n=0

def cprocess():
    global n
    n=n+1
```

Comment: by convention there should be space around `=`, also `n += 1`